# Flex 4 datefield No Error Rectangle with Date Validator

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am using DateField and validating date with a date validator. Its working fine but
when invalid date is there a usual red rectangle is not being shown around datefield
but if mouse hovered over date field a error tooltip is shown.

What shall I do to show a error rectangle around invalid dateField.

the ref code is

```
    <fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <validators:CodeValidator id="seriesVal" minLength="3" maxLength="3" required="true" source="{edSeries}" property="text" triggerEvent=""/>
    <mx:StringValidator id="remarksVal" required="true" source="{edRemarks}" property="text" triggerEvent=""/>
    <s:NumberValidator id="fromVal" minValue="0" maxValue="99999999" domain="int" required="true" source="{edFrom}" property="text" triggerEvent=""/>
    <s:NumberValidator id="toVal" minValue="0" maxValue="99999999" domain="int" required="true" source="{edTo}" property="text" triggerEvent=""/>
    **<mx:DateValidator id="txnDateVal" required="true" source="{edTXNDate}" property="text" triggerEvent=""/>**
</fx:Declarations>
```

.....

in init function

```
validatorArr = new Array();
validatorArr.push(txnDateVal);
validatorArr.push(seriesVal);
validatorArr.push(fromVal);
validatorArr.push(toVal);
validatorArr.push(remarksVal);
```

in OKbutton click

```
// First Validate Data if invalid data then continuw editing
if (Validator.validateAll(validatorArr).length > 0){
setFormFocus();
return;
}



<s:Label x="262" y="47.420326" styleName="FormLabel" text="Date"/>
<mx:DateField id="edTXNDate" x="337" y="40.570312" width="137" height="22" editable="true"
              formatString="DD/MM/YYYY" toolTip="Transaction date" yearNavigationEnabled="true"
              selectableRange = "{{rangeEnd : new Date()}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code in an empty application and could not reproduce the problem.  Which led me to suspect a few things

1. Try to disable any CSS in your application, and see if any CSS setting might have prevented the red halo around your app.
2. Remove all validators except the date validator and see if the issue persists.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Lin, CSS is the culprit. I commented out mx|datefield from css and the red rectangle appeared for the datefield textInput. Now in normal operation the datefield appears different than other textInputs. I wonder that other textInputs with same css style are showing red rectangle then why datefield textInput is not showing ? If I want to apply textInput style and show red rectangle also then what shall I do.

Comment: I suspect that your TextInput is spark component, and your DateField is mx component.  The CSS of spark and mx are a little different.  Check Adobe's documentation and see if the CSS you applied for TextInput is valid for DateField.

Comment: Yes Other TextInputs are spark so I defined another CSS mx|TextInput.FormEditMx and applied to DateField.TextInputStyleName but no luck. Without this property dateField shows error rectangle. I need to check adobe documentation for this now.